# Wrong label on button to change profile privacy on Career 2.0 French version

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I am reporting a "bug" on the French version of Careers 2.0.
English version seems to not have this bug.

In section "Mon profil" (My profile) > "paramètres de confidentialité" (privacy settings), labels of the public status button is inverted.

When my profile is set to "public" status. 
The button label is incorrect, it is displaying : "rendre mon profil public" (make my profile public)

> [image]

When my profile is set to "private" status.
The button label is incorrect, it is displaying : "rendre mon profil privé" (make my profile private)

Labels should be inverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now fixed this so the button has the correct label.